# Can't break out of simple while loop

Tags: ruby, loops, linked-list

I'm writing a search method for my DoublyLinkedList class as such:

```
def search(val)
  current = @head
  while current != nil
    if current.node_id == val
      return current
    else
      current = current.prev_node
    end
  end
  return nil
end
```

However when I try to use this search method I seem to be stuck in the while loop.

Here are my DoublyLinkedList and Node classes for reference:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :node_id, :next_node, :prev_node

  def initialize(node_id)
    @node_id = node_id
    @prev_node = nil
    @next_node = nil
  end
end

class DoublyLinkedList
  attr_accessor :head, :size

  def initialize
    @size = 0
    @head = nil
  end

  def add(node)
    if @head == nil
      @head = node
    else
      node.prev_node = @head
      @head.next_node = node
      @head = node
    end
    @size += 1
  end

  def search(val)
    current = @head
    while current != nil
      if current.node_id == val
        return current
        break
      else
        current = current.prev_node
      end
    end
    return nil
  end
end
```

Here's how I'm testing my method:

```
linked_list = DoublyLinkedList.new 
node1 = Node.new '1'
linked_list.add(node1)
puts linked_list.search(node1.node_id)
```

Sorry if for such verbosity(?) for such a simple question but I just can't see why my while loop won't break - it should return the found node's node_id!

Comment: Could you show your `Node` class as well?

Comment: It smells like a circular reference.  Try printing each node as you examine and see if your structure looks like what you think it should.

Comment: Hey BroiSatse - the Node class is posted at the top of the last code block.

Thanks Some Guy. Still trying..

Comment: `>> node1 = Node.new '1'
=> #<Node:0x007fd8a4192060 @node_id="1", @prev_node=nil, @next_node=nil>
>> puts linked_list.search(node1.node_id)
#<Node:0x007fd8a4192060>
`
what is your problem? it exactly printed the object you are looking for.

Comment: No idea I just made a new file with all my code and it works. For some reason the same code got stuck in a loop previously. Just one of those things...

Answer (score 0):

Try `break current` instead of `return current` to get out of a loop.